# How to preserve modification time of files after converting them to another format (e.g. M4A to WAV)?

Tags: bash, shell

For certain directories, I have to number files based on modification time so using the following Bash one-liner:

```
i=1; \
for f in $(ls -t); do \
  stripped=$(echo $f | sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]\+-\|\)//g'); \
  counter=$(printf "%07d\n" $i); \
  mv "$f" "$counter-$stripped"; \
  i=$(($i+1)); \
done
```

The result will be something like

```
file_a -> 0000001_file_a
file_b -> 0000002_file_b
file_c -> 0000003_file_c
```

But if I do conversions on some of the files (e.g., using `ffmpeg`) then the modification time changes and it would screw up ordering when coming back to this at a later time.

How could all the modification times preserved?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is `touch` (`touch -r` to be specific; see `man touch` output below):

```
for orig_file in *m4a; do \
  ffmpeg -i "${orig_file}" "${orig_file}.wav"; \
  touch  -r "${orig_file}" "${orig_file}.wav"; \
  rm $x; /
done
```

So, instead of the `ls -t` output of

```
0000001_file_a.wav
0000002_file_b.m4a
0000003_file_c.wav
```

becoming this after the conversion,

```
0000002_file_b.m4a.wav
0000001_file_a.wav
0000003_file_c.wav
```

it will remain the same (just with a different extension):

```
0000001_file_a.wav
0000002_file_b.m4a.wav
0000003_file_c.wav
```

---

Only seen `touch` used to create new files, but as it turns out, its main purpose is something else entirely; from `man touch`:

```
NAME
       touch - change file timestamps

SYNOPSIS
       touch [OPTION]... FILE...

DESCRIPTION
       Update  the  access  and modification times of each FILE to the
       current time.

       A FILE argument that does not exist is created empty, unless -c
       or -h is supplied.

       A  FILE  argument  string  of - is handled specially and causes
       touch to change the times of the file associated with  standard
       output.

       Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short op‐
       tions too.

       -a     change only the access time

       -c, --no-create
              do not create any files

       -d, --date=STRING
              parse STRING and use it instead of current time

       -f     (ignored)

       -h, --no-dereference
              affect each symbolic link instead of any referenced file
              (useful  only  on systems that can change the timestamps
              of a symlink)

       -m     change only the modification time

       -r, --reference=FILE
              use this file's times instead of current time

       -t STAMP
              use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time

       --time=WORD
              change the specified time: WORD  is  access,  atime,  or
              use:  equivalent  to -a WORD is modify or mtime: equiva‐
              lent to -m
```